# Using double quotes inside JSON keys or values

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to use double quotes `"` inside my JSON, but it doesn't work.

Here's my JSON

```
"I": {
        "1: Vehicle Con"trol:M": { 
            "D2": {
                "VM": "3300.00",
                "VSD": "324.04",
                "G":"1: Ve"hicle Control:M",
                "N":"-1"
            }
     }
```

Comment: Escape your data properly... Where is this data coming from/how is it being constructed? If you're using a library to serialise an array or object into JSON (like you should be), this will fix itself

Answer (score 4):

> [image: JSON specification]
>   [http://json.org/](http://json.org/https://i.stack.imgur.com/wog5V.png)

You can use `\"` in your keys or values to escape `"`

This Json is valid - tested on [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)

```
{
    "I": {
        "1: VehicleCon\"trol: M": {
            "D2": {
                "VM": "3300.00",
                "VSD": "324.04",
                "G": "1: Ve\"hicleControl: M",
                "N": "-1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "This Json is valid" - technically, that is :-)