# JSON broken when double quotes comes inside the key/value

Tags: java, json, regex

Sample data:

```
{"630":{"TotalLength":"33-3/8" - 36-3/4""},"631":{"Length":"34 37 7/8"}}
```

We are facing the double quotes issue in JSON response. How we can replace the double quotes with " \" " which comes inside the key or value? Java is the development platform.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405357/using-double-quotes-inside-json-keys-or-values

Comment: Do you own the code that is sending the response? You should ideally fix it there, rather than trying to escape it on the receiving end, which is a nightmare

Comment: Apart from being the wrong thing to do, you cannot fully solve this on the receiving side, there are cases where it becomes ambiguous.

Comment: @SureshAK Please for the love of everything that you find holy, stop this madness and go fix the back end.

Comment: @Matt  We are getting the above response from the client, we are not able to process them due to the incorrect format. Any help to process it from my side using java is appreciated.

Comment: Tell the client that they are sending you invalid JSON.  Get **them** to fix what ever is doing this.   It is the only sane thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is assuming that you are not in control of creating this JSON-like string. If you can control that part, then you should be escaping properly there itself.

In this case, since parsing systematically is not an option as it's not a valid JSON yet, all I could suggest is to go through the various strings and see if you can find a pattern on which you can apply some logic and escape all the `"`s which prevent the string from being a valid JSON.

Here is probably a way to start:

All of the `"`s that are needed to be there for the string to be a vaild JSON are surrounded by one or multiple characters among `{`, `:`, `,`, and `}`, with or without space in between the `"` and the other JSON characters.

So, if you parse the JSON-like string using Java and look for all the `"`s, and, when encountered with one, if they are along with any of the above characters (with or without space in between), you just leave it as it is. If not, replace that `"` with a `\"`.

Note that the above method may or may not work depending on the data in question. What I mean to convey is the approach that you may find useful if there's **absolutely no way** for the string to be escaped during it's creation, and, if these strings follow a strict pattern with respect to the unescaped `"`s.

Comment: Thanks. this is the exact scenario that we are facing. any codes that replace double quotes with  \" except the double quotes near to {  ,  :  }   will help us a lot.

Comment: Until you have a value like `a json example {"a":"foobar"}` and then this will become a nightmare

Comment: You should not even consider doing this. The only sane way to resolve the issue is to fix the sender. There is already too much lousy software in the world.